# Android app uses G+ native app's user

Tags: android, google-plus

I've implemented G+ sign-in following the quick start guide (PlusClient). Everything works fine. I can authenticate, get account meta data, disconnect, etc. The problem occurs when I post using the share intent. When I do this, the native G+ UI pops up showing the G+ logged in user and not mine? Is there a way to sync the two apps user sessions?

EDIT:
Following are relevant snippets of code. In addition, I am using two Google accounts (A & B). My app is authenticating and connecting as account A. The G+ native app has previously connected as account B. When I call the method post(), the G+ native UI pops up with the account B when I expected account A. Hope this helps. Submitting the entire working code base is not practical since it is a Cordova app.

```
public void connect() {
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this.cordova.getActivity() , this, this)
    .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
    .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
    .build();

    mPlusClient.connect();  
}

public void post(JSONObject params) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        String url = params.getString("url");

        com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusShare.Builder b = new PlusShare.Builder(this.cordova.getActivity());

        Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this.cordova.getActivity())
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText(params.getString("content"))
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse( params.getString("url")))
        .getIntent();

        MyApp app = (MyApp)this.cordova.getActivity();
        app.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, shareIntent, 256);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        raiseError("Error posting");
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
    try {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        } else if( requestCode == 256 ) {
            if( resultCode == -1 ) { //success

            } else { //fail and/or canceled

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.raiseError(e.getClass() + " - " + e.getMessage() + " - " + e.getStackTrace());
    }       

}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: @hichris123 I've updated the post with code and a bit more detail. I appreciate your looking at it. As you will see the is pretty basic code from the quick start guides.